# Two select statements in a single statement

Tags: sql, select, join

I basically have two tables called `images` and `users`. The `images` table has the following fields:

`i_id    |    s_id    |    u_id    |    name    |    filename    |`

`u_id` is a foreign key to the `u_id` field in the `users` table, which has these fields:

`u_id    |    username    |    password    |    email    |`

I'm running a query like this:

`SELECT s_id, u_id, name, filename, filesize FROM images WHERE name = 'fYhWId'`

This returns the `u_id` of the user, among other things. But I want to return the users username, not their u_id. So basically, within that SELECT statement, I also want to run:

`SELECT username FROM users WHERE u_id = 1`

I could use two queries for this, but I'm trying to cut down on the queries my application runs, and I know there's a way to combine this into one query, but I just don't know it :<

Does anyone know the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE u_id = (SELECT TOP 1 u_id FROM images WHERE name = 'fYhWId')
```

or

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE u_id IN (SELECT u_id FROM images WHERE name = 'fYhWId')
```

or

```
SELECT username,  s_id, images.u_id, name, filename, filesize 
FROM images 
INNER JOIN users on images.u_id = users.u_id
WHERE name = 'fYhWId'
```

Comment: Thanks, yours was the easiest to understand :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to join the tables

```
SELECT i.s_id, i.u_id,u.username, i.name, i.filename, i.filesize 
FROM images i 
INNER JOIN users u 
on u.u_id = i.u_id 
WHERE i.name = 'fYhWId'
```