# How to use the result of a select statement as a column of another select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

How can I use the result of an SQL `select` statement as a column of another SQL `select` statement?

**For example:**

```
select a, b,
    (select t from other_table where other_table.id = my_table.a) as c
from my_table
```

If the result of `other_table` is one record, there is no problem. But if it has more than one record, it is going to fail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224736/two-select-statements-in-a-single-statement

Comment: why not joining both tables on other_table.id = my_table.a ?

Comment: I think I should use a `cursor` or something.

Comment: @Jayvee the outer table might also have a Where clause

Answer (score 10):

I usually only use this kind of querying when counting. For example:

```
SELECT s.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product as p WHERE p.store_id=s.id)
FROM store as s
```

In this case there is always only one record returned and the query will work. Please note that this is just an example and you should use a join instead of a sub-query here.

In your case you could use the `TOP` keyword to limit the number of records in your sub-query to one:

```
select a, b,
    (select TOP 1 t from other_table where other_table.id = my_table.a) as c
   from my_table
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [CROSS APPLY](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/vbnet30/article.php/c15845/Using-TSQL-CROSS-APPLY-and-OUTER-APPLY.htm) like this:

```
select a, b, c.t
from my_table
cross apply (select t from other_table where other_table.id = my_table.a) as c
```

Answer (score -1):

No you can't use subquery like this because in subquery you will get one value and you can't select a value in sql query . you can only select the column name of the table . So this totally a wrong format of writing subquery.

Comment: Tnx, but as I said if the subquery has only one record for each row of the main query, it works.

Comment: I have this query (with a little changes) and it works now:
  `SELECT  Id,
          (select point from points where points.serial = table1.serial) as spoint,
           some_other_fields
     from table1`

Comment: I returns some records until it reaches to a serial that has more than one record in table `points`

Comment: @Shivam: Rahmani is right. The query syntax is correct and it works until the sub-query returns more than one record.